# Como mostrar datos recibidos en una comunicacion entre BrowserWindows usando Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

Tengo 2 BrowserWindow:

```
let AlgoWin = new BrowserWindow({width: 1280, height: 730);
let AlgoMasWin = new BrowserWindow({width: 1120, height: 550);
```

Estas 2 BrowserWindow cargan archivos html alojados en la carpeta `public_html` tal que asi:

```
AlgoWin.loadFile("public_html/index.html");

AlgoMasWin.loadFile("public_html/algoMas.html");
```

Según tengo entendido, para pasar datos entre BrowserWindows se podría hacer así:

```
AlgoWin.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
   AlgoWin.webContents.send('configInfo', Data);
});
```

Mi pregunta viene en este punto. Teniendo en cuenta que el `index.html` se ejecuta como si fuera de lado del cliente(por tanto no puedo usar require), como podría hacer para recibir los datos que quiera enviar desde el proceso principal de la aplicacion al `index.html` y usar esos datos para mostrarlos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que agregar un listener ipcRenderer dentro del HTML, en el caso de tener node deshabilitado debes precargarlo en el constructor de *BrowserWindow* de la siguiente manera:

1. Debes crear un script que contenga una referencia node a ipcRenderer y anclarlo al objeto window.

**preinit.js**

```
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

2. Defines la precarga en el constructor con **nodeIntegration** deshabilitado (por defecto).

**main**

```
let AlgoWin = new BrowserWindow({
     width: 1280, 
     height: 730,
     webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false,
        preload: __dirname + '/preinit.js'
      }
});
```

3. A partir de aqui puedes agregar el Event Listener dentro del html utilizando la referencia de ipcRenderer usando JavaScript.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
  <script>        
    window.ipcRenderer.on('configInfo', function (event, midata) {
       console.log(midata); // procesar aca
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El problema es que necesito usar eso en un archivo html, en el cual no reconoce la keyword `require` y por consiguiente ese codigo no funciona :(

Comment: tienes incluido el javascript en tu html ?

Comment: Claro, pero aun asi no lo detecta :C

Comment: intenta agregarlo en un tag script, deberia funcionar sin problemas, intenta noderequire tambien

Comment: y tienes la integracion con node en el constructor del browser window ?  webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }

Comment: Segun las directrices de seguridad de electron nunca hay que tener la nodeIntegration en true, es esa la unica forma?

Comment: ok, entiendo, voy a modificar la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona a la perfección, una última duda, es seguro utilizar este "truco"?

Comment: No es un truco, estas extendiendo el objeto window con una propiedad nueva.